# Change the default templates for a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates

I believe I've seen a demonstration of this somewhere but I can't remember where. I'd like to change a couple of the "Add New Item" templates for the project I'm working on. Also I'd like to include these changes in source control alongside the project so that anyone else who works on the project gets the same templates.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found where I saw it... this video http://mschannel9.vo.msecnd.net/o9/mix/09/wmv/t49f.wmv at 24:00 minutes. This isn't exactly what I want... almost, if my project was an MVC project this would work